# Rails AMS, specify different serializers in polymorphic list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, polymorphism, active-model-serializers, pg-search

I implemented a multi-table search using pg_search, and then serialize the result with Active Model Serializer (version 0.10) - it works fine, but AMS uses the default serializer for each of the types returned.

Here's the serializer:

```
class SearchBarSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :searchable_type
  belongs_to :searchable
end
```

Thus, for example, when serializing the returned objects from pg_search, if the relevant object is a "User", then AMS uses UserSerializer. If the relevant type is a league, then AMS uses LeagueSerializer.

That's fine - but I would like to use a different serializer for each type. This is for a search bar, and so I only care about a much smaller amount of data than the full standard serializer. (EDIT: the standard serializers serialize all attributes and associations for each of the User and League models, which can be seen below. Each model is somewhat significantly large, and for the purposes of just a search, I really only need each model's name and id, and perhaps some other smaller data for each type)

Is there some way that I can specify which serializer to use depending on the object?

Thank you!

EDIT:

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch

  #################### Associations
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  belongs_to :profile_page_visibility, optional: true # the optional part is just for when user's are created.
  has_and_belongs_to_many :leagues, class_name: "Leagues::League", join_table: "users_leagues_leagues"
  has_one :customer, class_name: "Payments::Customer", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :unpaid_charges, class_name: "Payments::UnpaidCharge", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :charges, class_name: "Payments::Charge", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :cards, class_name: "Payments::Card", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :league_join_requests, class_name: "Leagues::JoinRequest", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :notifications, class_name: "Notification", foreign_key: :recipient_id
  has_many :league_invitations, class_name: "Leagues::Invitation", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :teams, class_name: "Leagues::Team"
  has_many :divisions, class_name: "Leagues::Division" # Can act as division commissioner
  has_many :conferences, class_name: "Leagues::Conference" # Can act as conference commissioner
```

League Model:

```
class Leagues::League < ApplicationRecord
  enum pay_level: [ :basic, :custom, :premium ]
  include PgSearch

  #################### Associations
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, class_name: "User", join_table: "users_leagues_leagues"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :commissioners, class_name: "User", join_table: "commissioners_leagues_leagues"
  belongs_to :commissioner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :commissioner_id, optional: true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :feature_requests, class_name: "FeatureRequest", join_table: "feature_requests_leagues_leagues"
  has_many :join_requests, class_name: "Leagues::JoinRequest", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :invitations, class_name: "Leagues::Invitation", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :notifications, class_name: "Notification", as: :notifiable_subject, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :teams, class_name: "Leagues::Team", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :conferences, class_name: "Leagues::Conference", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :divisions, class_name: "Leagues::Division", dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: can you provide more info on the models you want to use for serialization and the polymorphic associations?

Comment: Done - I added info about each of the models. The polymorphic association comes from the pg_search gem (which performs a full-text search on a set of postgres database tables), meaning that each item in its returned list of objects it found is accessible through a polymorphic variable named "searchable"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to define a specific serializer lookup for your associations, you can override the `ActiveModel::Serializer.serializer_for` method to return a **serializer class** based on defined conditions.

For your case, it might look something like:

```
class SearchBarSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :searchable_type
  belongs_to :searchable

  class << self
    def serializer_for(model, options)
      return TinyUserSerializer if model.class == User
      return TinyLeagueSerializer if model.class == Leagues::League

      super
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey @Nathan did it work? if so, can you mark it as answer so others can take it too. Thanks.

Comment: noticed that I answered one of your past questions too - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104901/rails-activemodelserializer-combine-two-lists-of-same-type-models-into-one-seri. I hope you care the same for developers time as yours. thanks

Comment: Sorry, I was in the process of moving and just came back and saw this! It worked, thank you sincerely!

Comment: we appreciate your feedback!